# How To Safely Remove Hardware From USB Ports?

Tags: unity, usb

Today I connected my Amazon Kindle via a USB port. When I wanted to disconnect my kindle, I didn't see any option to remove USB device from the PC.

I am searching for the 'safe remove hardware' functionality in like in Windows. I'm afraid I'll make things crash and loose all my data if I just disconnect the USB cable by hand.

**How can I remove USB devices safely from my PC in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?**

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer. I almost forgot about that option, since I didn't use Unity in quite a while. Sorry...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu's default file manager, Nautilus, shows an eject button on removable devices.

Below you see a screenshot section of Nemo's sidebar when I have my Sony E-reader plugged in. Note the eject button right next to "READER".

[image: eject button]

You can also eject a drive by right-clicking on its icon in the launcher, and click "Eject", as in the image below. E-readers have a Flash Drive icon most of the time.

[image: Eject reader]

Comment: I would not install another third party software just to get a eject button which I can get from `Files` easily. In fact I am trying to keep as less program installed as possible to get faster computing experience. However nice to know some more info.

Comment: seppi lets keep it to Unity.

Comment: Unmount it manually?

Comment: the_seppi, this is really bad advice. In unity, you can very easily unmount stuff by right-clicking the icon in the launcher or clicking the up arrow on unity. No need to install an ancient ppa...

Comment: @Galgalesh I forgot that... Seems I've stayed absent from Unity for quite a while... I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: the_seppi, thx. I also added Unity screenshots.

Comment: @Galgalesh thx, makes it a bit more comprehensible for newbies

Answer (score 2):

Your system give me cause for concern.  Ubuntu does not act like Windoze and mount everything in sight.  Unless you made a script for this, Ubuntu will recongize it but will not force mount.  As for saftly removing just right click on your taskbar and eject device you can also do this open your Files and clicking the eject button next your kindles name under devices.

Comment: I guess my system is automatically opening the window because I installed a program to automatically detect my USB modem. Is this the cause? If so is auto opening is bad thing?

Comment: I find it more annoying than bad, but like you said you have program to auto mount your usb devices, which ok.